# Use DECLARE inside a VIEW in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do something like that:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
DECLARE @MAXDATE AS Date 
@MAXDATE = SELECT MAX(insertdate) FROM Mytable
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE insertdate= MAXDATE
```

Everyday new rows are inserted into my table, and I need to get the subset of the last insert. But I can't do it in this way as DECLARE is not allowed with views.

Anyone, anyidea?

thx!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE insertdate = (SELECT MAX(insertdate) FROM Mytable)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this as:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
    FROM Mytable t
    ORDER BY CAST(insertdate as date) DESC;
```

If `insertdate` is already declared as a date, then the `cast()` is not necessary:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS 
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
    FROM Mytable t
    ORDER BY insertdate DESC;
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `mytable(insertdate)`.

Comment: What if several rows were created on the same date?

Comment: @ColinMackay . . . I added the `with ties`.

Comment: As an aside, this query is not semantically equivalent to the first if the table contains only rows where `insertdate` is `NULL`. (Which is probably fine as it actually returns *more*, I'm not saying this answer is wrong.)